# oracledb - Not getting data after insert it

Tags: node.js, oracle, select

I'm trying to run SQL queries in node and it seems that oracledb module has a slightly different syntax from SQL syntax.

On `SQL PLUS` works fine but in the app, there is something missing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to commit your changes. Sometimes the databases reserve time for ACID operations.

`commit;`

and reload the app.

Comment: @LuisMendes535 Glad I could help. It would be very nice of you if you could select the option that states that my response solved your problem since it give me points. Best wishes. Tomás-

Comment: I don't find any option to set as solve and I can't upvote your comment because I don't have enough reputation . Sorry Thomas

Comment: Yes, just click on the tick below the downvote icon. Thank you @LuisMendes535

Comment: Thank you very much! Another thing I would like to stress is the title of the question: I do think it would be better if you renamed it to something like: ``oracledb not seeing data when selecting it after inserting`` or something like that. Your problem was not with the ``SELECT`` itself but with other thing. The point is to try to describe with a sentence your problem so if any other person were to have the same problem as you, they could google it with almost the same words. Just my humble suggestion. Best wishes Luis!